# how to pass a variable to a command in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, command, ros

i want the variable msg to be added to the path like /home/user/map/'msg'.
msg is a string type.Anybody knows how? thanks.

```
socket.on("savemap", function(msg) {

        console.log(msg);

        var cmd ='rosrun map_server map_saver -f /home/user/map/';
        exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {

        });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply concatenate using `+`.

```
var cmd = 'rosrun map_server map_saver -f /home/user/map/' + msg;
```

Or if you are on ES6 or higher, using [string templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
var cmd = `rosrun map_server map_saver -f /home/user/map/${msg}`;
```

Comment: Seems like we posted the same thing. I will delete mine :D